# How to fix 'New mailing' that only has 'Initializing' and edit boxes that wait forever

Tags: mailing, 4.6

One of my Civi installs has a problem where clicking 'New mailing' has 'Initializing' but nothing more, and edit boxes on the summary screen have a continuously circling triangle if an item is edited. I've been through this [forum help](http:////https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) and looking at the browser console I can see 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 54ms'.
I have removed extensions, and upgraded to the latest 4.6.27 CiviCRM release but no change. I really don't know what to do next, so very grateful for any help. CMS is Drupal 7.52 and PHP 5.6
(Added) The full message in the above browser console is:
'https://www.myapp.com/civicrm/ajax/angular-modules  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 34ms'

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy,

Please provide which Civi an CMS versions you're on.

Answer (score 1):

This problem turns out to be a mis-configuration on the shared server. We were also getting Internal Error 500 messages just on signing in today, but the hosting company (vidahost.com) fixed the problem & Civi is working fine now.  So not a problem with Civi, but a problem on the shared server, now fixed.  No wonder I couldn't find anything wrong with Civi..